# Removing characters from a file using VI

Tags: unix, vi

I want to use vi to get rid of all characters in the file that are not spaces and newlines. The syntax I know, removes the entire line which is not what I want, how can I edit it? Thanks.

```
:1,$g:[a-z|A-Z]:d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Global Substitution with Vim

With [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), you can use a global substitution to remove everything but spaces and newlines. For example:

```
:%s/[^ \n]//g
```